# Flutter cloud_firestore getDocuments() returns null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all the document ids in a collection. However it returns null.

My Collection looks like this:

```
/user_chats/myUid/users/userUid/characters/jbhv
```

Where the "userUid" is unknown.

Example: I want to loop through all the *"users"* (users/userUid/) and get their documentKey (userUid), and then delete the user that has a character with the name *"jbhv"*.

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('user_chats')
    .document(_firebaseUser.uid)
    .collection("users")
    .getDocuments()
    .then((snapshot){
  snapshot.documents.forEach((user) async{
    var userDocKey = user.documentID;
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection("user_chats")
        .document(_firebaseUser.uid)
        .collection("users")
        .document(userDocKey)
        .collection("characters")
        .document(characterModel.name)
        .delete();
  });
```

Why is my snapshot.documents = 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Run a query for all the documents containing the name. Then once you have all the documents you can perform a batch delete.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('user_chats/myUid/users/userUid/characters').where('name', isEqualTo: characterModel.name).getDocuments();

var documents = querySnapshot.documents;
```

Comment: This would work great, but the problem is that userUid is unknown.